# Hide files when deploying without Jekyll

Tags: github, github-pages

How can I hide specific deployed files when Jekyll is turned off (i.e. */.nojekyll* exists)? I have CSS and JS files under */res/* that are accessed from HTML files, but I don't want the files in */res/* to be accessible via *https://<username>.github.io/res/<file>*.